# maths on c:set variables

Tags: jsp, jstl

struggling with some c:set syntax (JSTL in JSP / Eclipse)

The choose / when (if) part and the initial c:set to row.sensorvalue works fine but than any attempt to perform maths on the variables results in the formula (rather than the result) ending up in decimalvalue and actualvalue.

Any assistance appreciated

```
<c:when test = "${row.typename == 'Temperature'}">

<c:set var = "initialvalue" value="${row.sensorvalue}" />

<c:set var="decimalvalue" value="${initialvalue}*0.1875"/>

<c:set var="actualvalue" value="((10.888 - SQRT((-10.888)^2 +4*0.0035*(1777.3-${decimalvalue})))/(2*-0.00347) + 30)"/>

<td><c:out value="${actualvalue}"/></td>

</c:when>
```

Regards
Ralph

Did manage to do this inside a scriplet (messy, but then I dont pretend to be a  developer) -

```
<%
String morecalcs = pageContext.getAttribute("calculatedvalue").toString();

//string to float
float forroot = Float.parseFloat(morecalcs);

//integer part for square root calcs
float fractionalPart = forroot % 1;
float integralPart = forroot - fractionalPart;

// square roote calcs
double actualvalue = (10.888 - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(-10.888, 2) +4*0.0035*(1777.3-integralPart)))/(2*-0.00347) + 30;

//1 decimal place
double rounded1 = Math.round(actualvalue * 10) / 10.0;
pageContext.setAttribute("finalvalue", rounded1);
%>
```

Comment: Expression is everything between `${` and `}`, i.e. only this part is evaluated, the rest is a text constant (literal). So you should use e.g. `value="${initialvalue*0.1875}"` instead `value="${initialvalue}*0.1875"` (i.e. put the **whole formula** inside the `${}`).

Comment: Thanks Jozef, first part working but strugling with the second part (variable is inside the formula)

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm - it's explained quite well.

Comment: getting 'The function SQRT must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified' but no clue how to fix this

Comment: Well, I would recommend to have a bean with these functions, such formulas do not belong to JSP.

Comment: Did manage to get it working inside a scriplet (getAttribute etc) but had to convert string to float, separate the integral part and then trim before sqrt would work and produce sensible output. Then setAttribute so I could use it outside the scriplet. Messy but then I dont pretend to be a developer. Added the code in case it helps / frightens anybody.